# Find most common element Linked List

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have this struct :

```
typedef struct data student, *pstudent;


struct data{
    char name[50];
    int value;
   pstudent next;
};
```

And I need a function that finds the most frequent student in a unsorted linked list.
For example: 
"John - value 3"
"David - value 2"
"Andrew - value 4"
"John - Value 9"
In this case, the function would return "John" because he appears twice.

Code so far:

```
void count(pstudent p)
{
    pstudent ptr1, ptr2;
    ptr1 = p;

   while(ptr1 != NULL && ptr1->next!=NULL)
   {
        ptr2 = ptr1;

        while(ptr2->next != NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(ptr1->name,ptr2->next->name)==0)
            {
                printf("Found %s, %s", ptr1->name,ptr2->name);
            }
        }
        ptr1 = ptr1->next;
     }
    }
```

How can I make this work? 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: What supposed to do `count()` function?

Comment: Count the duplicates in a List by name and return the most frequent one.

Comment: function `count` is assumed that the link list is sorted. also return type `void`

Comment: @CarlaPateiro and what it does now?

Comment: Yes, the function as it is now assumes the link list is sorted because I dont know whats the method for a unsorted one. The return needs to be changed also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to minimize the use of memory, traverse the list once.  For each name you encounter, count the number of times it also appears after the current position in the list.  Keep a record of the name with the highest count (and its count).  The first time you encounter a name will give you the highest count for that name.  This is an O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm, but only requires storage for a pointer to the name with the maximum count and the maximum count.  The cost is that it is slow on large lists.

The main alternative will be some algorithm that keeps tabs on names that are encountered and increments the count associated with that name as you encounter each name on the list.  This might be a hash function as suggested by [unxnut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202400/unxnut) or it might use direct copies of, or pointers to, the different names.  It requires an array of some sort, so for large lists, it might require a lot of storage (but is an O(N) algorithm as long as you're careful with the array management).

Thus, you're presented with a classic space-time trade-off.  A lot will depend on the size of the data sets you're going to deal with and the amount of repetition in the data set.  What works best for low-volumes may not work best at high volumes.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it will be to use a key transformation or hash function.  Use a hash on the name and if the hashed value matches, increment the count for that name by one.  Return the one with the highest count.